# How to dismiss keyboard in a UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I put a function in my code like this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textfield.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

where textfield is connect to a UITextField item.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
```

but when I run the program, actually I cannot hide it wherever I tap or click. Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: Have you connected ```textfield```'s delegate?

Comment: What is that??? I don't know actually.....

Answer (score 0):

Need to set delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textfield.delegate = self                  //set delegate 
}
```

Comment: Since there is an outlet, why do this in code? Connect the text field's delegate in the storyboard.

Comment: I added delegate setting. now I can dismiss keyboard by clicking on return button. if I want to dismiss it when I tap at anywhere on the screen. how and why ? thanks?

Comment: try this :  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

Answer (score -2):

add this delegate UITextFieldDelegate